# extern "C" function accessing code

Tags: c++, c, extern

Say I have the following C++ code:

```
int x;
some_class y;

extern "C" {
  void foo () {
    // do something with x
    // do something with y
  }
}
```

Do `x` and/or `y` need to be declared with `extern "C"`?

Comment: Have you tried compiling it? Is there a problem? BTW, variables in headers should usually be declared `extern` (without the `"C"`).

Comment: Yeah it compiled, but just because something compiles in C++ doesn't mean it is correct.

Comment: True, but it would improve your question to point these things out in the first place. That way, I wouldn't be left wondering whether yours is one of the countless SO posts that simply didn't bother to describe the problem or include the error message.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No. There is no restriction on `extern "C"` functions accessing functions and variables with C++ language linkage.

C++ `extern "C"` functions are often used to provide a C interface into code with C++ language linkage so it would be more than a little restrictive if this were the case.

Answer (score 1):

C++ methods/functions support overloading which make them link in a slightly more complicated way. What extern "C" does is really to say "don't let me overload and use the good old C way" which makes it compatible with C code.

Edit: Charles Bailey points out that I apparently was wrong about variables linking in an identical way. In other words, if the variables are used by external C code (which they could be since they're not static), you should put them inside extern "C". If you're only using them internally in the file or from external C++ code only, you're fine with keeping them where they are.

Comment: Variables don't have to link identically in C and C++, it is up to the implementation. That is why variables with external linkage have _language linkage_ and can be declared `extern "C"` if need.

Comment: Cool, I didn't know that and I've never seen it, I'll edit to reflect the information.

Answer (score 1):

well, variables aren't needed to be declared using `extern "c"`.
in fact, even functions aren't needed to use `extern "C"` just because you call them from a function with `extern "C"`

you can freely write code like:

```
    void bla() {cout<<"bla\n";}
extern "C" void sh() {bla();}
```

the function "sh" will compile using c++ compiler, so it can freely call bla. `extern "C"` affect only the name of the function.

Answer (score -2):

`extern "C"` is only useful for functions, not for data. It defines the way the function gets decorated or mangled. The decoration also depends on the calling convention used. Classes cannot be used from C, neither do functions that have classes as a parameter, even if inside an `extern "C"` block.

The `extern "C"` make sense where a C library is intended to be used by C and C++ code.

In conclusion having a class within an `extern "C"` does not make sense, `x` is just a basic type, having is inside or outside does not matter. The normal way to use the feature would be to have all the content of a header inside such a block. Having an `int` declaration in a header is not a good idea! That will create a variable for each translation unit and cause trouble at link time... Not sure what you intend to do with code similar to what you posted.

Comment: "*`extern "C"` is only useful for functions, not for data.*" That's not true -- e.g. I'd wager that your compiler's standard library implementation has `errno` declared with C-linkage.

Comment: Why isn't `extern "C"` useful for variables? Both function and variables with external linkage have _language linkage_.

Comment: "*Having an `int` declaration in a header is not a good idea! That will create a variable for each translation unit and cause trouble at link time...*" No, it's declared `extern`, so must still be defined in exactly one translation unit. Having an `int` _definition_ in a header file would be a bad idea...

Comment: Having a _declaration_ of an object with external linkage in a header file is not an issue if that declaration is not a definiton (e.g. `extern "C" int x;`). Having a declaration of such an object that _is_ a definition (e.g. `extern "C" { int x; }`) is an error if that header file is included in more than one translation unit.

Comment: Thanks for rectifying, I keep this broken answer alive, because of the good comments.